# How to create symlink for a directory with space in Linux

Tags: symbolic-link

I have a directory /home/user/pop music. I want to symlink to another directory /home/user/hello/pop music.

The command:

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/"pop music" /home/user/hello/"pop music"
```

only create 2 broken links under: /home/user/hello/

What is correct way to create this link?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What's the output of `type sudo`? (or `type -a sudo`, if supported). Did you show us the actual command? Or is there something else you omitted? (e.g. you want to run it on a server, we see the remote part and the real local command begins with `ssh`). Please do not respond in comments, [edit] the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use an escape character backslash after the space.

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/pop\ music /home/us
```